# X11 / xkb: Custom Keyboard Layout -- "Error loading new keyboard description"

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, keyboard-layout, xfce, xkb

My machine: Xubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, XFCE 4.14, X.org 1.20.13

I am attempting to create a custom keyboard layout for the Arabic-script (kona yéziq) version of the Uyghur language. I believe I have everything mostly correct and must just be missing something small to bring it all together.

This is the output of the command `setxkbmap -v 10 -layout "ug"`:

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     ug
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+ug+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
geometry:   pc(pc104)
Error loading new keyboard description
```

(I've also tried with the pc105 model setting, with the same result.) As the error message suggests, after running this command, my keyboard layout remains the same as before.

As I understand it, the relevant files here will be `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ug`, `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev`, and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`. I will paste `ug` in its entirety and then relevant lines that I have added from `evdev` and `evdev.xml`:

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ug`

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "ug" {

    name[Group1]= "Uyghur";

    key <TLDE> {    [     grave,    asciitilde  ]   };
    key <AE01> {    [     1,    exclam      ]   };
    key <AE02> {    [     2,    at      ]   };
    key <AE03> {    [     3,    numbersign  ]   };
    key <AE04> {    [     4,    dollar      ]   };
    key <AE05> {    [     5,    percent     ]   };
    key <AE06> {    [     6,    asciicircum ]   };
    key <AE07> {    [     7,    ampersand   ]   };
    key <AE08> {    [     8,    asterisk    ]   };
    key <AE09> {    [     9,    parenright  ]   };
    key <AE10> {    [     0,    parenleft   ]   };
    key <AE11> {    [     minus,    underscore  ]   };
    key <AE12> {    [     equal,    plus        ]   };

    key <AD01> { [ U0686, NoSymbol ] }; // چ
    key <AD02> { [ U06CB, NoSymbol ] }; // ۋ
    key <AD03> { [ U06D0, NoSymbol ] }; // ې
    key <AD04> { [ U0631, NoSymbol ] }; // ر
    key <AD05> { [ U062A, NoSymbol ] }; // ت
    key <AD06> { [ U064A, NoSymbol ] }; // ي
    key <AD07> { [ U06C7, NoSymbol ] }; // ۇ
    key <AD08> { [ U06AD, NoSymbol ] }; // ڭ
    key <AD09> { [ U0648, NoSymbol ] }; // و
    key <AD10> { [ U067E, NoSymbol ] }; // پ
    key <AD11> { [ bracketright, U00BB ] }; // ], »
    key <AD12> { [ bracketleft, U00AB ] }; // [, «

    key <AC01> { [ U06BE, NoSymbol ] }; // ھ
    key <AC02> { [ U0633, NoSymbol ] }; // س
    key <AC03> { [ U062F, U0698 ] }; // ژ ,د
    key <AC04> { [ U0627, U0641 ] }; // ف ,ا 
    key <AC05> { [ U06D5, U06AF ] }; // گ ,ە 
    key <AC06> { [ U0649, U062E ] }; // خ ,ى 
    key <AC07> { [ U0642, U062C ] }; // ج ,ق
    key <AC08> { [ U0643, U06C6 ] }; // ۆ ,ك
    key <AC09> { [ U0644, NoSymbol ] }; // ل
    key <AC10> { [ U061B, colon ] }; // ؛, :
    key <AC11> { [ apostrophe, quotedbl ] }; // ', "

    key <AB01> { [ U0632, NoSymbol ] }; // ز
    key <AB02> { [ U0634, NoSymbol ] }; // ش
    key <AB03> { [ U063A, NoSymbol ] }; // غ
    key <AB04> { [ U06C8, NoSymbol ] }; // ۈ
    key <AB05> { [ U0628, NoSymbol ] }; // ب
    key <AB06> { [ U0646, NoSymbol ] }; // ن
    key <AB07> { [ U0645, NoSymbol ] }; // م
    key <AB08> { [ U060C, greater ] }; // ،, >
    key <AB09> { [ period, less ] }; // ., <
    key <AB10> { [ U0626, U061F ] }; // ؟ ,ئ

    key <BKSL> {    [ backslash,         bar    ]   };
};
```

(I have considered the possibility that breaking from the default tab style is causing the issue, but 1. none of my text editors produce the same kind of tab, 2. I have seen examples of modified layouts that do the same thing, and 3. what would be the point of using brackets and semicolons then?)

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev` (lines 208-224)

```
  classmate     us              alt-intl        =       pc+us(classmate-alt-intl)
  classmate     us              altgr-intl      =       pc+us(classmate-altgr-intl)
  nokiarx51     cz              qwerty          =       nokia_vndr/rx-51(cz_qwerty)
  *                     $sun_custom     $sun_var        =       pc+sun_vndr/%l%(v)

! model         layout                          =       symbols
  *             ug                      =       pc+ug // This is the line I've added.
  *             ar                      =       pc+ara
  *             ben                     =       pc+in(ben)
  *             bs                      =       pc+ba
  *             cs                      =       pc+rs
  *             cz_qwerty                       =       pc+cz(qwerty)
  *             dev                     =       pc+in(deva)
  *             dvorak                  =       pc+us(dvorak)
  *             dzdwi                   =       pc+bt
  *             el                      =       pc+gr
  *             en_US                   =       pc+latin
```

(I have tried a few different options in place of `pc+ug`, which all produced the same effect, but notably those changes did show up in the output of `setxkbmap`, so I know that I have the correct file.)

`/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` (lines 1330 - 1352)

```
      <vendor>Megawin Technology</vendor>
     </configItem>
    </model>
  </modelList>
  <layoutList>
    <layout>
      <configItem>
        <name>ug</name>
        <shortDescription>Uyghur</shortDescription>
        <description>Uyghur (Kona Yeziq)</description>
        <languageList>
          <iso639Id>uig</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
      </configItem>
      <variantList/>
     </layout>
    <layout>
      <configItem>
        <name>us</name>
        <!-- Keyboard indicator for English layouts -->
        <shortDescription>en</shortDescription>
        <description>English (US)</description>
        <languageList>
```

The changes that I've made to `evdev.xml` do populate in the XFCE keyboard settings dialogue, but selecting the keyboard layout from there simply does nothing. At all stages of debugging, I have liberally exited my session and logged in again before determining that an attempted solution has failed.

Comment: Remove all comments, I suspect one char is illegal even inside comment like `]` or `;`